# Problems adding a Module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.7

I have gone through couple of tutorials to add custom module in Magento. I am not very familiar with Magento but I tried to follow the steps online. 
I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.
So to add customer module I created folders as ***Mehul/Helloworld*** into *app/core/local*.

my ***Helloworld/etc/config.xml*** is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The root node for Magento module configuration -->
<config>

    <!--
        The module's node contains basic
        information about each Magento module
    -->
    <modules>

        <!--
            This must exactly match the namespace and module's folder
            names, with directory separators replaced by underscores
        -->
        <Mehul_Helloworld>

            <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
            <version>0.0.1</version>

        </Mehul_Helloworld>

    </modules>

      <!-- This node contains parameters, available on frontend --> 
    <frontend> 
        <!-- Module aliases are located in this block --> 
        <routers> 
            <!-- This node's name should be the same as our alias --> 
            <helloworld> 
                <!-- use parameter specifies which of basic routers needs to be used. 
                This can be "standard" for frontend or "admin" for backend --> 
                <use>standard</use> 
                <!-- router arguments block --> 
                <args> 
                    <!-- This parameter specifies the full name of out module --> 
                    <module>Mehul_Helloworld</module> 
                    <!-- This parameter sets module alias --> 
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName> 
                </args> 
            </helloworld> 
        </routers> 
    </frontend>

</config>
```

my ***app/etc/Mehul_Helloworld.xml*** is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mehul_Helloworld>

            <!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->
            <active>true</active>

            <!-- Which code pool to use: core, community or local -->
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </Mehul_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And my controller file *'IndexController.php'* into ***Helloworld/controllers*** directory is,

```
<?php 

    class Mehul_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

        public function indexAction()
        {
            echo "Hello tuts+ World";
        }
        public function testAction()
        {
            echo "test action";
        }
    }
?>
```

I disabled my all **catch** through admin panel and I flushed it too.
I can see my module is enabled when i go to *System/Configuration/Advance*
but I try to see my controller as,

*mysite.com/helloworld/index/index* and 
*mysite.com/helloworld/index/test* 
Then I am getting an 404 error message saying that Page Not Found!

What should I do now?

- Local

  - Mehul

    - Helloworld

      - controllers

        - IndexController.php
      - etc

        - config.xml
- etc

  - Mehul_Helloworld.xml

Comment: `local` should be in `root/app/code` and lowercased. `etc` should be in `app` folder too. Try to connect mysite.com/helloworld/

Answer (score 0):

Hi there's an online tool for module creation pretty good for new persons. This tool will give you a compressed file. You ca try this and see what mistake you are doing.

Tool url:http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Answer (score 0):

Your files structure looks to be strange a little.
It should be app > code > local and app > etc > modules . From task description I can see that local folder is on the same level with etc folder. Please, check this and fix. Also try to use lower case in "local" folder name.

Answer (score 0):

I think every thing is correct, but you have typed structure incorrect here . But the "Mehul_Helloworld.xml" file should be in

> "app/etc/modules/Mehul_Helloworld.xml"

instead of

> "app/etc/Mehul_Helloworld.xml"

. Thats may be the reason your modules is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

*app/etc/Mehul_Helloworld.xml* should be *app/etc/modules/Mehul_Helloworld.xml*

And your code must be into

*/app/code/local/Mehul/Helloworld/*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys!! It works fine, I was typing wrong URL! 
The URL should be 'mysite.com/store/helloworld', as my magento is installed in saperate store directory istead of root directory.
And I was trying to access mysite.com/Helloworld. 
I realized it after I looked at my directory structure carefully! 
anyway, Thank you guys for the responses!